# Consensus anomaly about read-write registers and test&set

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

I read this answer below and got into another question.

[Why is the consensus number for test-and-set, 2?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33031/why-is-the-consensus-number-for-test-and-set-2)

I also read that read/write registers have consensus number 1.

But I see that in test&set (also in compare&swap) by using read write registers alone, we still arrive at consensus.

I think I am missing something very fundamental here. Need help.

The protocol in the accepted answer of the link is as mentioned below

> Suppose that we have two threads 0 and 1 that need to reach consensus.
>   We could do this by letting each thread follow the consensus protocol
>   below:
>
> 1. Write your proposed value to A[t], where t is the thread id and A is an array of size 2
> 2. Perform the test-and-set instruction on some register R, with R initialised to 0.
> 3. If the return value is 0, you were first: return A[t]. Otherwise, you were second: return A[|t−1|].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consensus number and consensus hierarchy are defined in the classic paper ["Wait-Free Synchronization"](https://cs.brown.edu/~mph/Herlihy91/p124-herlihy.pdf) by Maurice Herlihy, 1991.

Note the keyword: ***wait-free***.

Since you did not give the algorithms for test&set using read/write registers only, I guess that they are *not* wait-free. (They may be lock-free instead.)

---

***Added:***

After the discussions with the OP in the comments, I realize that the OP has not fully understood the difference between atomic test&set registers and atomic read/write registers. He/she thought that the protocol given in the post uses read/write registers only. In fact, it uses test&set registers/operations/instructions in the second step.

A test&set register supports the test&set operation, which is a combination of test and set that cannot be interrupted. See this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) for more details.

Comment: Thanks hengxin. I have edited the question with the protocol, that was provided in accepted answer. I agree with the wait-free part, but I see that in the proofs for test&set and read-write registers we have problem of consensus itself, rather than being wait-free.

Comment: @ultimatecause The protocol in the answer to the linked post implements consensus using test&set. It is not a protocol implementing consensus using only read/write registers. "I see that in test&set (also in compare&swap) by using read write registers alone, we still arrive at consensus." I want to know such protocols and I guess that they are not wait-free.

Comment: Oh, so I think there lies the key. I only see read-write registers there, what is that I am missing?

Comment: @ultimatecause In the second step, it use the "test-and-set instruction". So it uses test&set registers. If it were a read/write register, only the read or write operations can be applied.

Comment: Do you mean, two consecutive operations by same process without being interleaved, in which one is read and other is write are not allowed? Because in the tree for read/write registers in  Maurice Herlihy's paper two processes one reading and the other writing on same register is allowed. Test&Set instruction also uses read-write registers alone.

Comment: @ultimatecause Test&set is an atomic operation that read/write registers do not support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62272/discussion-between-ultimate-cause-and-hengxin).