# Are Test and set primitives as powerful as semaphores?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization

I get confused because i don't know if it is possible to use **Test and Set** primitives in case where more then one process can be enter in critical section at the same time.

Comment: Test and Set is a primitive operation, used as a building block to implement more powerful operations.

Answer (score 5):

Your hunch is correct, they aren't equivalent. Test-and-set has a [consensus number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)) of 2, which means, roughly speaking, that it is only able to efficiently synchronize between 2 processes. See [Why is the consensus number for test-and-set, 2?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33031/why-is-the-consensus-number-for-test-and-set-2). Semaphores allow synchronization between an arbitrary number of processes (assuming no bound on the number of processes waiting on a semaphore).

It isn't really a “fair” comparison, since test-and-set is a hardware primitive while semaphores are a software interface. But if does show that test-and-set isn't sufficient to implement ([wait-free](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)) semaphores.